# What is the value of the Septuagint for Judaism?

Tags: translation, targumin, septuagint

Translations of the Tanach into Aramaic (targumim) have been accepted as authoritative and shed light on the meaning of some Hebrew words and expressions.  They are freely used by commentators.  But the earlier translation of the Tanach into Greek (the Septuagint) was never accepted as authoritative.  Why, since it was done independently by 72 rabbis, who even introduced tiny changes to dispel misconceptions? [Megillah 9a]

Because it was not in the language of most Jews?  Because it was requested under semi-coercion by a foreign power?  Because it used original versions of Tanach later modified by the Sanhedrin?  Because it was later associated with Christianity?  But none of these arguments remove the possibility of us understanding the Hebrew of the Tanach better by looking at the Septuagint, especially since the Greek it uses is well understood.

Have we, ever, used the Septuagint to shed light on the meaning of some expressions in the Tanach?  (I know, for example, that the Septuagint has a version of Ashrei that includes a line beginning with nun.)  Is there a halacha prohibiting this?

Comment: The Septuagint itself has undergone changes non-Jewish hands and isn't an exact replica of what the 72 wrote for Ptolemy.. The Septuagint itself  has different version based on the editing of different non-Jewish religions

Comment: Aside from @Schmerel's point, the narrative in the Gemara tells us that the 72 translated only the five Chumashim. So the translation of Tehillim, for example (with the "nun" line), isn't from them anyway.

Comment: And by the way, while I don't know of classical Jewish sources that refer to the Septuagint, R' Aryeh Kaplan does so fairly often in his translation/commentary, The Living Torah. (Thus indicating that presumably there's no halachah against doing so.)

Comment: I'm told Rabbi Reuvein Margulies wrote at length regarding this question.

Comment: @Meir the Septuagint is divinely inspired by G-d.